# boost asio timeout

Tags: c++, boost, timeout, boost-asio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a timeout on blocking sockets in boost asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291871/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-blocking-sockets-in-boost-asio)

I read some of the entries before about the timeout but I don't understand.

I want a defined timeout for the connection.
the connect code looks like:

```
try{
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver              resolver(m_ioService);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query       query(link.get_host(), link.get_scheme());
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator    endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator    end;
  boost::system::error_code                   error   =   boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

  while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
   {
    m_socket.close();
    m_socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
   }
}
```

also I want a read timeout.

I use `boost::asio::read_until(m_socket, response, "\r\n");` for read the header.

is it possible to set SIMPLE a timeout?

Comment: Read [how to set a timeout on blocking socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291871/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-blocking-sockets-in-boost-asio) It seems that there is not easy way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fist of all I believe that you should ALWAYS use the async methods since they are better and your design will only benefit from a reactor pattern approach.
In the bad case that you're in a hurry and you're kind of prototyping, the sync methods can be useful. In this case I do agree with you that without any timeout support, they cannot be used in the real world.

What I did was very simple:

```
void HttpClientImpl::configureSocketTimeouts(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
#if defined OS_WINDOWS
    int32_t timeout = 15000;
    setsockopt(socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    setsockopt(socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
#else
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec  = 15; 
    tv.tv_usec = 0;         
    setsockopt(socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
    setsockopt(socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
#endif
}
```

The code above works both on windows and on Linux and on MAC OS, according to the OS_WINDOWS macro.

Comment: Isn't there some library I must include to make this work?

Comment: gives error: ‘HttpClientImpl’ has not been declared

Comment: Can you please help me to find why your answer [does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668717/boost-asio-blocking-mode-timeout-on-native-socket-handle-is-not-working) for me?

Comment: Setting the socket options may not have the desired affects on the Asio operations.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30428941/1053968) for details.

Comment: Has someone actually got a timeout implemented with the code above using Linux? When using windows everything works fine. However, when I compile and run this with Ubuntu, both `setsockop` calls do not return an error code but the read-calls are still blocking?

Answer (score 5):

Using boost::asio and the sychronous calls like read_until do not allow for easily setting a timeout.

I'd suggest moving to asynchronous calls (like async_read), and combining that with a deadline_timer to accomplish this goal.

Comment: +1 for recommending async calls.

Comment: Good luck with async asio.  I had mysterious crashes using them, not often, but enough to doubt the application's stability.  They all went away when I switched to multiple threads each with synchronous asio.

Comment: Sorry that you've had problems with boost::asio.  While it's definitely a learning curve and there are a lot of things that have to be done "just right", I've found that for cross-platform development of applications under heavy network load (to the point that synchronous calls like select(), were causing major bottlenecks), boost::asio has performed extremely well and given definite benefits.

Comment: @wally async programming is hard to get correct, nobody will deny that. The inversion of the application's flow control is particularly confusing at times.

Comment: @Chad What a pity is that `deadline_timer` is not avialble when I use the standalone [`asio`](https://think-async.com/Asio/) which doesn't depent on `Boost`. Any idea about how to accomplish this goal with standalone `asio`?

Comment: The documentation for non-boost have both deadline_timer and steady_timer listed?  https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.2/doc/asio/reference.html

Comment: You may no longer need the deadline timer.  You can make one async call, get a future, and then call `run_one_for` or `run_one_until` on the `io_context`.  You don't want to do this with a context shared with other stuff that might be going on because you have to `restart` the context between calls.