# Elegantly stop the thread for blocking or non-blocking when accept or receive using asio and C++11

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, boost-asio

I am using asio for tcp server and I plan to use C++11 std for thread as well.  My final goal is to have this application on Linux but I am testing it on Windows first using Visual Studio 2015.

First I am using blocking so I found there were discussion on how to stop a thread waiting on accept.  There were pre-C++11 solutions such as pipe, and select. I am looking for the asio way.

```
    asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));
    backAcceptor = &acceptor;
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);

    asio::error_code ec;
    acceptor.accept(socket, &ec);
```

Second way is to use asynchronous, but I prefer to use the asio header only.  The compile complained that the asio::placeholder doesn't have this member but according to the comment, the solution is applied:

```
    asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(message_),
        std::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2
            ));
```

run() still block there.  And I am looking for method to resume this thread from main.

```
    asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp_server server(io_service);
    io_service.run();
```

The third way is, to set a timeout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041016/boost-asio-timeout).  But it doesn't stop my accept.  Plus, the answer was in 2012.  I hope there is new was to solve this by now.

### Update

To test the scenarios, I first have a thread to either blocks at synchronous accept() or at asynchronous run().  When the thread is running, the main then waits for 2 seconds, and tries to stop the thread.  Then I wait for the thread to complete using join.

For the first method "Synchronous", I tried to use acceptor.cancel() and the thread arrived at the join.  Is this the correct way?

Second method "Async", although I am still not clear how to stop this thread officially, I succeeded using io_service.stop() to actually cancel it.

Please let me know whether my solutions is correct and I will continue to try different solutions.

Comment: Just use std::placeholders::_2 for the second placeholder?

Comment: got it compiled.  So now I realized the example from asio pdf still uses run() which blocks.

Comment: You can use run_one and poll_one if you don't want to block in cases where you have an external event loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727568/whats-the-difference-between-boostio-service-poll-one-and-run-one

Comment: Need a better error indicator than "complained here". `::run()` only blocks while an outstanding operation is in the cue, unless you create a `io_service::work` object. Your question is unclear because you're asking 3 questions in one. Anyway, running the io_service is going to take just as long manually as it is using `::run()` and you're going to block. Blocking has to happen somewhere, which will end up happening at `::run()`, which is typically why you designate a separate thread or thread pool to run the io_service.

Comment: @Ralf, from the name, poll_one looks like the one I need. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have played around with a non-typical approach with `run_one` and no threading, that specifically allows you timeout individual "non-asynch" operations:

- [boost::asio + std::future - Access violation after closing socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442464/boostasio-stdfuture-access-violation-after-closing-socket/33445833#33445833)

In fact, you do post the asynch operations, but then you call `await_operation` with a timeout:

```
async_connect(socket, ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve({address, port}), raise());
await_socket(std::chrono::seconds(6));
```

This is the equivalent of doing a synchronous `connect` **but** with the possibility to timeout. No threads, blocking `run()` or other puppies were harmed.

See the linked answer for demos

---

PS. Use `deadline_timer` with `posix_time` if you don't want the `high_resolution_timer` which works nicely with `std::chrono`

Comment: is your suggestion on server side?  Your link points to a client example.

Comment: @splash my technique applies to any operation that could be lengthy. As such you can apply it wherever asynchronous operations are used, but a semi synchronous work flow is preferred, like in this case the OP has.

Comment: can you provide example of stop the accept for the server side?