# Timeout for boost::beast sync http client

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am adapting the [synchronous HTTP client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/sync/http_client_sync.cpp) from the [Boost Beast examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html). Unfortunately the example client does not include timeout options and sometimes gets stuck in my workloads. I tried adding timeouts with

```
beast::get_lowest_layer(stream).expires_after(NetworkSettings::BASIC_TIMEOUT);
```

before calling write/read operations, but those only seem to work when using async_read/write. [From what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291871/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-blocking-sockets-in-boost-asio), it seems that basic boost asio supports timeouts only for async operations. So my question is whether beast has any capabilities to use a timeout on the blocking connect/read/write calls.

Comment: I don't have experience in Beast, but Have you tried using `std::future` and its `wait_for` member function? asio library (wrapped by beast) supports `use_future` which emulates blocking behaviour as synchronous clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timeouts are not available for synchronous I/O in Asio. Since Beast is a layer above asio, it too does not support timeouts for synchronous I/O. If you want timeouts, you must use asynchronous APIs. You can use a stackful coroutine, or if you have a modern enough compiler you can experiment with stackless coroutines (`co_await`). These allow you to write code that appears synchronous but using asynchronous interfaces.

The Beast docs are clear on this:
*"For portability reasons, networking does not provide timeouts or cancellation features for synchronous stream operations."*

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/timeouts.html

If you want to have timeouts on connect operations, use an instance of `beast::tcp_stream` and call the `async_connect` member function:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/timeouts.html#beast.using_io.timeouts.connecting

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll just use the asynchronous operations then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

try change `stream.connect(results)` to

```
auto Future = stream.async_connect(endpoint, net::use_future);
if(Future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::future_status::timeout){

   std::cout<<"timed_out";
   ....
}else {

}
```

Bunch of things to note:

1)You may need below header files

```
#include<boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
#include<chrono>
#include<future>
```

2) Since you are asyc_* initiating; you need to call `ioc.run();`

3) You need an another thread to execute `ioc.run();` as we are mocking synchronous via asynchronous-- someone have to run the event-loop.

Another approach: you can explicitly set the socket option using its native handle (I've never done it). But before doing that, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850018/5198101

```
const int timeout = 200;
::setsockopt(socket.native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&timeout, sizeof timeout);//SO_SNDTIMEO for send ops
```

https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

> SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO Specify the receiving or sending timeouts
>   until reporting an error. The argument is a struct timeval. If an
>   input or output function blocks for this period of time, and data has
>   been sent or received, the return value of that function will be the
>   amount of data transferred; if no data has been transferred and the
>   timeout has been reached then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN
>   or EWOULDBLOCK, or EINPROGRESS (for connect(2)) just as if the socket
>   was specified to be nonblocking. If the timeout is set to zero (the
>   default) then the operation will never timeout. Timeouts only have
>   effect for system calls that perform socket I/O (e.g., read(2),
>   recvmsg(2), send(2), sendmsg(2)); timeouts have no effect for
>   select(2), poll(2), epoll_wait(2), and so on.

Comment: This would refute the idea of using async IO in the first place, right?

Comment: @sehe Hmmm...for sure  blocking IO isn't a good thing( (in-case of scale-ability), but it looks like, the OP is stuck experimenting synchronous client, so I gave a work-around.

Comment: @Explorer_N Yes, there's no need for futures or non-portable socket options since Beast provides an asynchronous connect function that has a timeout (see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/timeouts.html#beast.using_io.timeouts.connecting) I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @VinnieFalco, thanks for responding, you know, the OP is aware of timeout operation provided by `async_*` , but he said he is experimenting synchronous client which means he wants to block till the `connect` happens and it looks like there is no `timeout` for `sync connect` and that is the reason I suggested `std::future`... Sure `co_await` works too, but at the end, it is just an another asynchronous model like `std::future`..About `setsockopt`-- I leave it up-to the OP's discretion by linking an answer which talks about portability. you still think my answer is incorrect ?

Comment: @VinnieFalco and you think `std::future` won't do the Job which OP is looking for?

Comment: Well `std::future` uses the asynchronous API (e.g. `async_connect` with `net::use_future`). In that case, you might as well use `beast::tcp_stream` since that will actually cancel the connect for you on a timeout, instead of leaving the operation outstanding which is what happens with the future using the code above.

Comment: @VinnieFalco "instead of leaving the operation outstanding which is what happens with the future "  not necessary, OP can call `cancel` on timeout which indeed cancel the pending operation, moreover, the whole reason for `future` is OP wants to block, using timeout on `beast::tcp_stream`-- will it give a blocking behaviour?

Comment: @VinnieFalco, Even from your response what I can see is (correct me if I am wrong) My answer isn't incorrect, yet, it is a plausible one.